# Field/Record Loss During MS-Access Paste

Tags: ms-access, copy-paste, data-loss

OK, this should be really simple so it's baffling that it isn't. I'm doing a very basic copy of data from Excel and paste append into an Access database. So why are values and sometimes entire records vanishing?

Details: I'm using Access 2016 in Windows 7 importing data from Excel workbooks supplied by a subcontracting lab into our database. The lab doesn't always use exactly the same format to report their results, so importing directly from Excel becomes unreliable. I would love to use an append query but they work poorly if the data is one column to the right of where it ought to be.

Instead I have a messy little temporary table with no primary key and five fields, all short text and some VBA to validate, tidy, and properly import it. Copy from Excel, Paste Append into Access and... WTF?!? Fields paste in with null values. Occasionally records vanish. No Paste Errors Table, no error message. Just data gone!

There is a pattern to the missing data. I have 5 fields, the first two are always text, the next two are always numeric, and **the last field is sometimes numeric and sometimes text.** Unsurprisingly the problem is in this last field. If all of the data in the 5th field is numeric then everything works fine. Similarly if all the data n field 5 is text. **It's when there is a mix of numeric data in some records and text in others that data vanishes** and it's the text that's pasting in as nulls. If the first record contains text in field 5 it goes missing altogether.

Why?!? This should be the easy part! Ironically, the VBA works fine.

Fixes that I have tried:

- Converting the Excel workbook to CSV to avoid hidden formatting or similarly unhelpful problems on the Excel end.
- Building a fresh database to avoid inherited gremlins. A database consisting of nothing more than the single table of five short text fields experiences the same issues.
- Stripping potential trouble characters. While not a special or reserved character, the "<2" had me concerned, but "bob" fails to import just as mysteriously.
- Changing fields to long text, making them required, or setting primary keys. The text values still paste in as nulls and, if it's set to "Required", shunts the entire record to the Paste Errors table.
- Importing the records one at a time. This actually does work in that the data pastes correctly but is less than desirable when working with 1000 plus records. It does suggest that it isn't the structure of the database that's the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the problem.  When I changed the fifth field to text both the numbers and text were properly appended as text.  the import wizard worked after I added a header row to the Excel File.  Copying the Excell data, and going to the Access Ribbon Home Tab-Paste Append also worked.

Comment: Can you post a link to that database Mazoula? I'd love to be able to compare it to mine.

Comment: nothing in them but hopefully here you go: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13fgU7XlYEYH4HU4mwiagbhYOwe9Z82nM/view?usp=sharing                                     https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UoVORnBnwncfkZLnevQIxr3l2K0hDEPU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I **finally** found [the answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/access-2007-paste-append-problem/93b8f4fa-e24f-4712-9668-7f1fe3a8daf4?page=1). It's a little known bug somewhere in Excel, Access, or the clipboard and appears to have been around since at least 2007. Records with both text and numeric data in a field will lose the text data upon paste append to a text field.

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, apple
8, 9, 10, 11
12, 13, 14, berry
15, 16, 17, 18
```

Paste Appends from Excel to Access as

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7
8, 9, 10, 11
12, 13, 14
15, 16, 17, 18
```

**The "solution" is to close Excel before you Paste Append.** This dark ritual will cause the data to append correctly. I have no idea why this is but have confirmed it with my own database.